# How to capture Bcc address while auto case creation

Tags: apex, email, case, inboundservices

we have enabled email to case creation in sfdc everything works fine.

But,now i have a requirement like to create a case whenever ever particular to as well as bcc address.Now i need to create case whenever to is MR:x and Bcc Mr:Z

How i am gonna capture because in email handler also i can't get bcc address.

I didn't find any documentation to capture Bcc address

Answer (score 0):

**[BCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy)** stands for ***Blind* Carbon Copy**. The entire point of specifying a recipient in this way is that **you cannot see the address**.

> Blind Carbon Copy (BCC) is an option available in most email clients that allows the sender to send the message to a list of BCC addresses (in addition to primary recipients) without other addressees knowing about that fact. BCC addresses are concealed from recipients, including others on the BCC list.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for quick confirmation i will check with my team.